# How to configure ssh authentication with ldap without password

Tags: ssh, ldap, openldap

I need to setup ssh authtication with ldap without using password
like amazon EC2 instance with pam file.

Also if I need to use this with multiple servers, 
How can I configure that?

Answer (score 0):

You need openssh-lpk (https://code.google.com/p/openssh-lpk/). I do not know if there is a package for ubuntu though; last time I used it I had to apply patch and make my own package.